# Django manytomany relationship over 2 apps

Tags: python, django, django-models, uml

I'm trying to create a relationship where a clients can favorite vendors and stores, and on my class diagram (see bellow image) i have the following relations:

In the first app i have a person object, which is inherited by vendor and client
In the second app i have only a store object (Which have backwards relation to vendor, but it's not show on class diagram, this is the reason that's the second app to be instantied)

The problem is that client have manytomany relation to vendor and another manytomany relation to store, but the relation client/store generate a error, cause the app2 is isntantied after app 1.

Is there any way to make generic manytomany relation?

Cause clients can have many vendors and many stores, stores can have many clients, and vendors can have many clients

[image: class diagram]

The code i used:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Nome", max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField("Descrição", max_length=300)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'store'

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField("Primeiro Nome", max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField("Ultimo Nome", max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'core'


class Vendor(Person):
    bio = models.TextField("Bio", max_length=300, blank=True)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField("Ultima Atualização", auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'core'


class Client(Person):
    favorite_stores = models.ManyToManyField(Store)
    favorite_vendors = models.ManyToManyField(Vendor)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'core'
```

This code give me the following error:

```
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/core/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from store.models import Store
  File "/store/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from core.models import Vendor
```

And what i want to see in the admin is simple as that:
[image: admin]

Comment: Have a look at: https://github.com/coleifer/django-generic-m2m

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just add two ManyToMany relations, instead of importing the "Store" model, use a string directly (to avoid circular dependency)

```
class Client(Person):
   favorite_stores = models.ManyToManyField('store.Store')
   favorite_vendors = models.ManyToManyField(Vendor)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two mistakes here. The most obvious is that you have a circular dependency: one models imports the other, which imports the first... You can escape this by not importing the models, and referring to the other via strings.

The other mistake is one I see quite a lot here. You don't want ManyToMany on both sides of the Client model. Actually, Client *is* the linking table of the many-to-many relationship between Store and Vendor. As such, you actually need ForeignKeys on both sides.

So, Client should be:

```
class Client(Person):
    favorite_stores = models.ForeignKey('core.Store')
    favorite_vendors = models.ManyToManyField('core.Vendor')
```

Comment: Actually, I can't see why core needs to import Store at all, but never mind.

Comment: How i will have many stores related to client using foreign key for favorite_stores?